# How are topological insulators connected to quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-computer, topological-insulators

I see lots of references in news articles on how topological insulators can be used to make a working quantum computer but I'm not sure how a protected edge state is going to lead to a quantum computer.

I thought that the fundamental point was to have a system in more than one state and the result could eventually only be determined by measurement. In this case, what are those different states and what is the measurement operation?

Comment: A topological insulator is a way of storing a quantum bit. If you can toggle a material from conductor to a Mott insulating state you can input a qubit and store it there.

Comment: So the two states are conducting and insulating? If so, how does one get a topological insulator into a superposition of the two?

Comment: As far as I know, the proposal is not to use a topological insulator alone, but in connection with a superconductor. There you can have a superposition of different states, though it is not clear whether you could have a quantum superposition. It's clearly ongoing research, and we're still really far from the realisation of a topological quantum computer. Check Wikipedia on this topic for more details.